# How to round a time stamp to hour in HANA

Tags: hana

I have a timestamp column  in HANA and I want to round of those timestamp to hours which means

```
time
_____
2016-09-03 10:27:09
```

I want this to be like

```
time
_____
2016-09-03 10:00:00
```

Any help is apprecited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want the minutes and seconds truncated? How about subtracting the minutes and seconds from the date like so:

```sql
SELECT ADD_SECONDS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    - MINUTE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * 60 
    - SECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) FROM DUMMY
```

If you really want to *round* so that 30 or more minutes are rounded up to the next hour you would need to work with CASE to either subtract minutes/seconds or add the remaining minutes to the next hour:

```sql
SELECT ADD_SECONDS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    CASE WHEN MINUTE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 30
    THEN -MINUTE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * 60 - SECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ELSE (60-MINUTE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) * 60 - SECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    END
) FROM DUMMY
```

Replace `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with your timestamp column as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQLScript

```
do begin

declare lv_ts TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

select 
    case when minute(:lv_ts) >=30 
    then
        ADD_SECONDS(
            :lv_ts, 
            (60 * 60 - (minute(:lv_ts) * 60 + to_int(second(:lv_ts))))
        )
    else 
        ADD_SECONDS(
            :lv_ts, 
            -1 * (minute(:lv_ts) * 60 + to_int(second(:lv_ts)))
        )
    end
from dummy;

end;
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: Two minutes faster! :). - But yours keeps the microseconds because of the to_int(), which is probably not wanted. Yours returns `23.02.2017 15:00:00.483` right now.

Comment: So is this more faster

Answer (score 0):

Use `series_round()`. This is the fastest way to round time stamps, especially if you use it in group by.

```
select series_round('2016-09-03 10:27:09', 'interval 1 hour') from dummy
```

Check out the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/435ec476ab494ad6b8409f22abec13fe.html) for additional rounding options.